# SharePoint 2010 and Email List View

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I need some creative thinking here...

I have a webpart page with two webparts. Webpart #1 allows the user to select from some filter options....the options selected affect webpart #2 that displays a listview determined by the filter options.

What I would like is to add a button to the page that will allow me to email the current listview on the screen. Almost like a screen/print and paste into outlook.

Maybe some javaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Take look at [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), it will allow you to take a screenshot of the current page, you can then export the image for use in outlook